# How can I make each row in the resultset returns multiple times?

Tags: mysql, sql, resultset

I'm writing an application that uses Mysql and for now my tables don't have many data in it. I want to test how my application handles a larger amount of data. In order to do that I need each row in the resultset to repeat itself several times.

I know that I can run the query and UNION it with the same query and UNION that with the same query. Is there a different way that makes it easier for me to choose how many duplications will occur?

Comment: Please stop writing tags in titles. You've done it in pretty much all of your 239 questions.

Comment: If you don't mind, please explain how would I write my title better? I was just trying to be as clear as I can in the title.

Comment: I have already made the edit. You wrote "mysql sql: " at the start of your title; the _question tags_ feature exists to do this job for you, in a consistent and indexable way. They should not be duplicated in titles.

Comment: ok thank you! I'll make sure not to do these mistakes again.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have a table to insert into

To generate dummy data. http://www.generatedata.com This will generate the data as well as the insert scripts.

Then Just create a massive dataset

Comment: awesome website! thank you. in this specific case it won't do me any good because I can't have false data. I need to have valid data but duplicated.

Comment: @ufk - if it were me then I would have PHP loop the insert if its a one off

Answer (score 0):

You could do a cross join on itself, which would yield 2^n results, but it's all going to be dirty hacks